# What does "thinking talents" mean or what does it refers to in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

Utilizing thinking talents in work situations.

Comment: *Thinking skills* would be more idiomatic. It means "Use your head."

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, as a British English speaker it doesn't really resonate with me at all.

I can only surmise that it *might* refer to people who think a little differently to the mainstream and who come up with left-field ideas that make people say "oh yes, good idea. I never thought of that - it might well work"